# how to return data with oder_by count in codeigniter active records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables which contain `restaurant_id` in each table, I'm trying to get data on `uhd_restaurant` join `uhd_user_order` and `uhd_order_history`

this is my code :

```
$this->db->DISTINCT();
$this->db->select("t1.restaurant_id,t1.restaurant_name,t1.restaurant_code, COUNT(t1.restaurant_id)as total");
$this->db->from("uhd_restaurant as t1");
$this->db->join("uhd_user_order as t2","t1.restaurant_id = t2.restaurant_id","left");
$this->db->join("uhd_order_history as t3","t1.restaurant_id = t3.restaurant_id");
$this->db->group_by("t1.restaurant_name");
$this->db->order_by("total","desc");
$res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $res;
```

that code will be return to be :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "365"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(8) "Yukihira"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "MG99"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "88"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "367"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(5) "alice"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "ZF42"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "363"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(6) "takumi"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "ZO09"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "368"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(5) "test1"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "WS94"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "366"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(6) "nakiri"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "XN27"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

In my table `uhd_user_order` have 3 `restaurant_id`, which

`364` have 1 , `365` have 8, and `366` have 1

and in my `uhd_order_history` have 4 `restaurant_id` which

`365` have 11, `363` have 2, `368` have 2 and `367` have 3

so the total should be

`365` = 19, `363` = 2, `364` = 1, `366` = 2 `367`=3 and `368` = 2

but i return the wrong data, see my `365` its return total with `88` but it should be `19` my `366` only return `1` and i cant return `restaurant_id` `364`

so the data should be return to this :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "365"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(8) "Yukihira"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "MG99"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "19"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "367"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(5) "alice"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "ZF42"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "363"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(6) "takumi"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "ZO09"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "368"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(5) "test1"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "WS94"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "366"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(6) "nakiri"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "XN27"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(3) "364"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(6) "test"
    ["restaurant_code"]=>
    string(4) "WY58"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

P.S in `uhd_restaurant` have all `restaurant_id` in `uhd_user_order` and `uhd_order_history`

guy can you help me how to get the right total of data ?

Comment: remove your DISTINCT(),and use only group_by..I think this may work.

Comment: How uhd_user_order and uhd_order_history are connected?

Comment: they are not connected on each other, they connected on `uhd_restaurant` with `restaurant_id` @Kamal

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("t1.restaurant_id,t1.restaurant_name,t1.restaurant_code, COUNT(t1.restaurant_id)as total");
$this->db->from("uhd_restaurant as t1");
$this->db->join("uhd_user_order as t2","t1.restaurant_id = t2.restaurant_id","left");
$this->db->join("uhd_order_history as t3","t1.restaurant_id = t3.restaurant_id");
$this->db->group_by("t1.restaurant_name");
$this->db->order_by("total","desc");
$res = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $res;
```

Comment: there is no any change

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this query in CodeIgniter.. [Though there is some error in your ideal result set but it will give you hint...]

```
SELECT t1.restaurant_id,t1.restaurant_name,t1.restaurant_code, SUM(total) FROM ( SELECT t1.restaurant_id,t1.restaurant_name,t1.restaurant_code, COUNT(t1.restaurant_id)as total FROM uhd_restaurant as t1 LEFT JOIN uhd_order_history as t3 ON t1.restaurant_id = t3.restaurant_id GROUP BY t1.restaurant_id UNION ALL SELECT t1.restaurant_id,t1.restaurant_name,t1.restaurant_code, COUNT(t1.restaurant_id)as total FROM uhd_restaurant as t1 LEFT JOIN uhd_user_order as t2 ON t1.restaurant_id = t2.restaurant_id GROUP BY t1.restaurant_id) as t1 GROUP BY t1.restaurant_id ORDER BY total DESC
```